# Proper way in NodeJS to load a cjs in a module project

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to develop code for a bot which uses a webpage as primary developing base, which means, action code must be written on the web page. So I guess the code in question is loaded on server side then run by eval when appropriate.  It's ok for a few lines of code, but in a large project you can imagine the kind of nightmare it can be.

So my goal is to setup a testing environment, and have that code under a Git repo. Then, once my tests pass, I can upload the code.

Now, my particular problem at hand is: now I want to be able to load a JavaScript file from a NodeJS module, load a function and be able to run that function from a test suite:

Code for sarasa.js:

```js
function sarasa2(){
    console.log( " aca toy!");    
    return true;
}
```

Testing code:

```js
import { Test } from "../../myjsunit/testSuite.js";

import  fs from 'fs';


class so_Test extends Test {
    
    test_load_and_run(){
        let fname = "testsjs/micro/sarasa.js";
        
        let code = fs.readFileSync( fname ).toString() ;
        
        eval( "("+code+")" );
        
        let actual = sarasa2();

        this.assertTrue( actual );
        this.done();
    }
}

export { so_Test }
```

(Please do not worry about testing framework)

The error I get is:

> ReferenceError: sarasa2 is not defined

Is it possible to run the function defined inside the loaded file?

Comment: Did you try to use the `require` function yet?

Comment: @zer0 missed that one, thanks, going to test now

Comment: Either don't use parenthesis around your `eval`'d expression, or assign the result of the expression to a variable. A function expression will not introduce an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

hint provided by @Zer0 was right. You can have a nodejs project mixing module and commonjs, provided there is a package.json in the propper directories: I had to setup a directory exclusively for commonjs code then require() from the unit testing.

"production" code:

```
module.exports.sarasa2 =  function sarasa2(){
    return true;
}
```

or

```
function sarasa2(){
    return true;
}

module.exports = { sarasa2 }
```

testing code:

```
import { Test } from "../../myjsunit/testSuite.js";
import { createRequire } from 'node:module';

class so_Test extends Test {

    test_load_and_run(){
        let path = process.cwd();
        let fname = path+"/testsjs/micro/sarasa.cjs";

        const require = createRequire( fname );
        let code = require( "./sarasa.cjs" );

        let actual = code.sarasa2();

        this.assertTrue( actual );

        this.done();
    }
}

export { so_Test }
```